# SQL Update according to unique values

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am busy creating a VB.Net Windows Application. I am using a microsoft sql server database with a table called skedulering. I am trying to update a column (i.e Groep) with unique values based on another column (i.e. Kode). This value takes the first three characters of the Kode value and adds a integer to it. I think what I mean is best explained with the following :

[image]

All the red bordered rows have the same Groep value. Can anyone please help me to create the sql statement?

Regards

Comment: Why is there no `CAS3` in your example for `CASGrKIRES` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dense_rank() to generate a running no

```
UPDATE t
SET    Groep = left(Kode, 3) + convert(varchar(10), rn)
FROM
(
    SELECT Kode, Groep, rn = dense_rank() over (partition by left(Kode, 3) order by Kode)
    FROM   yourtable
) t
```

Comment: Fantastic. Working great. Would never have figured it out on my own. Thank you Squirrel.